# Add CAD feature class to Arcgis using arcpy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.1, autocad, data-frame, indexerror

I'm trying to add a CAD layer (point, polyline, annotation...etc) into ArcMap by python code, i'm using Arcgis 10.1, IDLE(Python 2.7), 
I faced many codes but they all gives errors, so i'm blocked here !

I tried this :

```
arcpy.AddCADFields_conversion("C:/Saadia/SAFTOP/Parcelle et rivrains/simulation arcgis/python-script python/Progr_work/plan.dwg","ADD_ENTITY_PROPERTIES")
```

And also this :

```
arcgisscripting gb = arcgisscripting.create()
gb.ImportCAD_conversion("'C:/plan.dwg'", "C:/workspace")
```

But no one works !

I tried this :

```
import arcpy
arcpy.env.workspace = "D:/Users/saadiya/Documents/ArcGIS/Default.gdb"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0] 
addPoint = arcpy.mapping.Layer(r"C:\plan.dwg\Point") # reference to point layer
addPolyline = arcpy.mapping.Layer(r"C:\plan.dwg\Polyline") # reference to Polyline layer
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, addPoint, "BOTTOM")
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, addPolyline, "BOTTOM")
```

But i got this error :

> RuntimeError: Objet\xa0: CreateObject can not open the map

I changed it to this :

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\Saadia\BD\Projet_Marrakech.mxd")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0] 
addPoint = arcpy.mapping.Layer(r"C:\plan.dwg\Point") # reference to point layer
addPolyline = arcpy.mapping.Layer(r"C:\plan.dwg\Polyline") # reference to Polyline layer
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, addPoint, "BOTTOM")
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, addPolyline, "BOTTOM")
```

it fixed this error :

```
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Can you share some of the code you used? Also, can you clarify what you mean by "cad code"?

Comment: Thank you dassouki for answering.
This is the code i used

import arcgisscripting
gb = arcgisscripting.create()
gb.ImportCAD_conversion("'C:/plan.dwg'", "C:/workspace")

And about CAD feature class, it results from AUTOCAD !

Comment: you can click on the "edit" button and edit your question by providing perhaps a bit more detailed explanation

Comment: I used to this one :
£
arcpy.AddCADFields_conversion("C:/Saadia/SAFTOP/Parcelle et rivrains/simulation arcgis/python-script python/Progr_work/plan.dwg","ADD_ENTITY_PROPERTIES")

Comment: So no one knows the answer, i'm sure that is an easy task !

Comment: It's hard to try and understand what you're trying to do and what your end goal is. In a previous comment, I had asked you to modify your question and add more detail and code it by clicking on the "edit" button above, instead you added your code in the comments. It is very difficult to read the code that way and I highly suggest you add the code to the body of your question and not as a comment.

Comment: I can understand it ! i'm working on this

Comment: What do you mean by adding CAD fields to ArcGIS?  Are you simply trying to add a CAD layer (point, polyline, annotation...etc) into ArcMap by python code?

Comment: Yes exactly artwork21

Comment: This question seems to have changed during the interactions with its answerer.  If the answer does not provide a solution for you can you consider revising it to make what you are asking now clearer, or start a new clear question, please?

Answer (score 2):

You may use the [AddLayer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s300000025000000) method:

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0]
addPoint = arcpy.mapping.Layer(r"C:\Temp\my.dwg\Point") # reference to point layer
addPolyline = arcpy.mapping.Layer(r"C:\Temp\my.dwg\Polyline") # reference to Polyline layer
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, addPoint, "BOTTOM")
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, addPolyline, "BOTTOM")
```

Comment: It gives me this error :

Object: CreateObject Layer invalid data source. While i'm trying to executing the third line !

Comment: Can you edit your question with your updated code?

Comment: I did it artwork ...

Comment: Your problem seems to be on this line, mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT").  My example was with running the code in a opened ArcMap session within the python window.  Instead of using CURRENT value you can set this path to whatever map document you want the layers added to.

Comment: I edited my question again ! please check the change !

Comment: Do you have a dataframe name "Layers" at index 0 in that map doc?

Comment: Now yes ! 
artwork i think the problem is that the function Layers get as parameter just a .lyr file !! because i get this error :
ValueError: Object: CreateObject Layer invalid data source